# Getting an object value whose key is a number in handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js, mustache

Saving my variable as `updated.colors['hi']` and accessing it with `{{colors.hi}}` works fine, but if I try to replace hi with a number, even if it's in quotes, it gives me this error message:

```
Expecting 'ID', got 'NUMBER'
```

Is there any way to format this right without creating a helper?

Comment: Not enough info.

Answer (score 0):

If **updated.colors** is an **array** you can access it's elements like this:

```
{{updated.colors.0}}
{{updated.colors.1}}
```

If **updated.colors** is an **object** you can access it's keys like this:

```
{{updated.colors.hi}}
{{updated.colors.hello}}
```